# How to replace the number in a dataframe in a particular range in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that has a variable named 'EntrySec' and I want to replace the values if it falls in a certain range.

```
Entrysec
1
21
32
9
43
66
```

Expectation: replace all values by

10 if it falls in the range between 1-10
20 if it falls in the range of 11-20
30 if it falls in the range of 21-30   and so on

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i was creating a new variable df['entrysec_0-10']=df['EntrySec].between(0,10) and so on  for diff ranges. But i dont want it that way, i want to replace it within df['EntrySec'].

Answer (score 6):

Here is a very simple solution that works for any number (it doesn't matter in which range a number is). It rounds the values of a Pandas DataFrame's column to the next *ten*:

```
df["Entrysec"] = df["Entrysec"]//10*10+10
```

---

**How does it work?**

1. Perform the *integer division* by 10 (it basically cuts off the fractional part of the normal division). In this way you obtain the *tens* of a number. For example:

   - 43/10=4.3 (normal division)
   - 43//10=4 (integer division)
2. Multiply by 10, getting the original number without its *ones*. For example: 4*10=40.
3. Add 10 to get the desired result. For example, 40+10=50.

---

**Edit**

While my solution rounds a value to its next *ten*, the user wants to round e.g. 20 to 20 (and not 30). This can be achieved by slightly modifying my approach:

```
df["Entrysec"] = (df["Entrysec"]-1)//10*10+10
```

In this way it is possible to get the desired output. Here are some corner cases:

- 9 is rounded to 10
- 10 is rounded to 10
- 11 is rounded to 20

Note that with this approach 0 is rounded to 0, as implicitly asked.

Comment: Good Answer. An explanation on the math would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Try using df.loc

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Entrysec': [1, 21, 32, 9, 43, 66]})
```

and then

```
df.loc[(df["Entrysec"] >= 1) & (df["Entrysec"] <= 10), "Entrysec"] = 10
df.loc[(df["Entrysec"] >= 11) & (df["Entrysec"] <= 20), "Entrysec"] = 20
df.loc[(df["Entrysec"] >= 21) & (df["Entrysec"] <= 30), "Entrysec"] = 30
```

for range of 100 we can have:

```
j = 1
for i in range(1,10):
    df.loc[(df["Entrysec"] >= j) & (df["Entrysec"] <= i*10), "Entrysec"] = i*10
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 10

Entrysec
0   10
1   30
2   40
3   10
4   50
5   70
```

Comment: What about larger numbers? You can't hardcode all the possibilities...

Comment: What about bigger ranges??

Comment: Then we only change loop upper limit `for i in range(1,10)` to whatever upper limit is say 1000 then we change upper limit to 100 `for i in range(1,100)`

Comment: This approach works but is much much complex for large ranges...